# How to stop headless Python Selenium from stealing window focus?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

I'm using Python Selenium in headless mode and I have some parts of the script that open new tabs, do clicks, etc.

However, it keeps stealing my computer's window focus and putting it on the script. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

For example: I'm doing literally anything else on my computer, say typing this post, and my selenium automation focuses on it's logging window and my typing on this window stops working.

Comment: I have a same problem, did you found any solution? :(

Comment: @fer0m Not yet, I think most likely it's stealing it when doing actions that create a new tabs and / or switch between them. The best solution I have so far is just to not create new windows.

Comment: Same issue here. Any luck with a solution?